# Static IP address without a gateway

Tags: debian, networking, gateway

Simple setup here. I have a machine with multiple network interfaces, two for example - `eth0` and `eth1`.

`eth0` has a static address and has a default gateway assigned.
`eth1` has a static address and will not have a gateway on that interface's network address range.

#### The Question

Do I need an entry in network configuration file (`/etc/network/interfaces`) for the `gateway` option on the interface that does not have a gateway on its network, `eth1` in the above example?

#### Additional Questions

If I do something like:

```
gateway 127.0.0.1
```

Will this have adverse effects? Will this interface now have a way to reach a gateway or will using the loopback interface as a gateway have no effect (i.e. same as leaving the `gateway` option off entirely)?

#### Example config for discussion

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Interface 1
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.10.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.1.10.1

# Interface 2
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.100.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 127.0.0.1     # This is the line in question
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need a `gateway` entry for any NIC that you don't want to use to reach a network not in its collision domain (192.168/16 in this case).  You can just omit that line if you don't want a gateway for that NIC.

I'm not sure what will happen if you try to use loopback as a gateway, but I wouldn't expect it to be happy times.

Comment: I haven't tested but I would guess that trying to set 127.0.0.1 as a gateway for 192.168.100.1 will not work because they are in disjoint networks: 127/8 vs 192.168/16.